# how to omit iterations of documents with non existent keys or null values using map method

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('tables').snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    List<DocumentSnapshot> tabledocs;
    List<Marker> markers = [];
    ......
    tabledocs = snapshot.data.documents;
    markers = tabledocs.map((doc) {
      if (doc.data.containsKey('tablegeolocation')) {
        return makeMarker(doc);
      }
    }).toList();
    ......
```

I am trying to use map function to iterate through the results of the firestore request and omit the documents which do not have a field named "tablegeolocation".

The above code still returns a `null` marker even if it doesn't have a field named "tablegeolocation".

```
stream: Firestore.instance.collection('tables').where("tablegeolocation", isNull: false).snapshots(),
```

I tried changing the `stream:` by using `where` `isNull:false` but the compiler throws an assertion saying `isNull` should only be used with `true`. And there is no `isNotNull` operator:(

I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a where to filter the data before returning the map, something like this:

```
markers = tabledocs
  .where((doc) => doc.data.containsKey('tablegeolocation'))
  .map((doc) => makeMarker(doc))        
  .toList();
```